# Presentation of $\mathbb{P}^2 \#\mathbb{T}$

Tags: algebraic-topology

how do I find the presentation of the fundamental group of $\mathbb{P}^2\#\mathbb{T}$? I only know that it is a quotient of the free group of rank 4 by the least normal subgroup containing the elements of the form $\alpha_1^2 \alpha_2^2 \beta_1 \beta_2 \beta_1^{-1}\beta_2^{-1}$. Thanks.

Comment: You can produce $\#$ with `$\#$`

Comment: my apologies...

Comment: @Jr., You should probably accept your own answer to this question or explain why it is unsatisfactory. Otherwise, if this stay without an accepted answer it will haunt us for ever! :)

Comment: What $\sharp$ means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that answer is obvious: the free group of order 4 (generated by $a,b,c,d$) such that $a^2 b^2 c= dc d^{-1}$, am I right?

Comment: Yes, assuming $\mathbb P^2$ means $\mathbb P\#\mathbb P$.

Comment: It's not really clear what you were originally confused about, since you seemed to state the answer in your question.

Comment: @JimConant I think that the problem is what do I mean by "a presentation", after thinking about it, I remembered the definition.